# How to make fwrite() consistent in writing data to a file

Tags: c, fwrite

I am writing data to a file, however on sudden power offs I can see garbage data in the file sometimes.

Sometimes the data is missing, sometimes it is editted and sometimes its a garbage data just before my first entry to the file on system reboot.

Is there a way I can make sure fwrite is consistent?

Just to add I am using "a" to append data to the file everytime.

Further, the garbage values or indermined data which I am seeing in the file, is it really due to the fwrite() operation?

Comment: What platform and what filesystem are you on?

Comment: I am using FAT32 and SMX rtos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FAT32 is not a [journaling filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system), so there is no way to guarantee consistent writes. Even if you flush the disk buffers after each write, the data could still be corrupted if there is a power loss just as the data is written to disk.

To answer your other question, no, the garbage isn't caused by `fwrite` at all, it is because the filesystem has not completed the write operation in its entirety.

Comment: Although, if it were important enough, you could implement some basic journalling features within your output format.

Comment: @Dana the Sane: Correct, and I think that's the best the OP can do in this situation.

Comment: Alternatively, since this seems to be an embedded system, OP could try to alter the hardware requirements to include a big enough capacitor or battery to ensure that writes can be completed after a "power failed" signal occurs. However this might be an unacceptable increase in cost. On the other hand if you're already using a batter, you just need to monitor it better...

Answer (score 3):

Right after writing, call `fflush(3)` (to flush user-space buffers), and then either `fsync(2)` or `fdatasync(2)` to make sure that all the data has been written to the device.

Comment: Wouldn't it cause overhead after every write? I am writing one line at a time of 200 chars aprprox.

Comment: It will, but it's the only way a user-space program can instruct the kernel to write all the data to disk. You may also consider calling `fsync(2)` at larger periods.

Comment: @Punit: Of course it will. This is the cost of trying to tell the C library and operating system what to do.

Comment: The OP just explained he isn't using a standard C implementation, nonetheless I upvoted this because of it's application to ISO C.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what implementation of FAT your embedded OS is using.  If you're using [smxFS](http://www.smxrtos.com/rtos/fileio/smxfs.htm), then you should take advantage of the following:

```
The DOS/Windows FAT file system is inherently not power fail safe, so smxFS 
implements features to compensate for this:

   1. sfs_chkdsk() API can check and fix many problems, such as cross-linked 
files, lost chains, bad directory entries, and other problems. Flags specify 
which types of problems to fix (or none). It indicates the results using flags 
in the return value and can give detailed text information in a buffer, to 
allow a human operator to correct problems. Please see the smxFS User’s Guide 
for details.
   2. Clean shutdown checking determines whether all files were closed and 
caches flushed before the system shut down. If not, sfs_chkdsk() should be called.
```

If you expect unexpected power losses, you should consider a capacitor or backup battery that will allow you to finish a write correctly.  You'd probably want sfs_fflush and sfs_fclose (or maybe even sfs_fclose, as it looks like it flushes itself)

There are other filesystem options [listed here](http://www.smxrtos.com/fs.htm), although they might not all be suitable for your application as not all of them can be read OOB by a computer.

Comment: I am using exactly what you have mentioned above but sfs_chkdsk() doesn't help me in fixing file(garbage values etc) issues, it could fix file system issues though.